# Using Jsawk to parse JSON access logs

Tags: json

With our new webservers, the access logs are in JSON and I'm not able to use typical awk commands to pull out traffic info. I've found jsawk, however I keep getting a parse error anytime I try to pull anything out of the access logs. I have the feeling that the logs are not in a format the the parser likes

Here is a sample entry from the logs:

```
{ "@timestamp": "2014-09-30T21:33:56+00:00", "webserver_remote_addr": "24.4.209.153", "webserver_remote_user": "-", "webserver_body_bytes_sent": 193, "webserver_request_time": 0.000, "webserver_status": "404", "webserver_request": "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", "webserver_request_method": "GET", "webserver_http_referrer": "-", "webserver_http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36" }
```

So for example if I want to pull the IP addresses out of the logs, I would use this:

```
cat access.log | jsawk 'return this.webserver_remote_addr'
```

However this only results in 'jsawk: JSON parse error:' and the entire access log printed.

Am I correct in assuming that the access logs are in a format the parser doesn't recognize? Each entry in the logs is all on one line. How can I get jsawk to parse properly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
$ echo '{ "@timestamp": "2014-09-30T21:33:56+00:00", "webserver_remote_addr": "24.4.209.153", "webserver_remote_user": "-", "webserver_body_bytes_sent": 193, "webserver_request_time": 0.000, "webserver_status": "404", "webserver_request": "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", "webserver_request_method": "GET", "webserver_http_referrer": "-", "webserver_http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36" }' | jsawk 'return this.webserver_remote_addr'
```

and got this:

```
24.4.209.153
```

Updates:
I think the problem is that you have each line as a json object, and there are multiple lines in access.log. There's a good way to work around at here: [How to use jsawk if every line is a json object ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117843/how-to-use-jsawk-if-every-line-is-a-json-object/27118019#27118019)